# Azure .Net SDK to generate APIM resource identifier / subscription

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-sdk-.net

I'm looking at this [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.apimanagement.apimanagementsubscriptionresource?view=azure-dotnet) to generate APIM subscription key in my c# application.

I couldn't find the right way to get the class instance **ApiManagementSubscriptionResource** and invoke this method **CreateResourceIdentifier(String, String, String, String)**. Anyone can shed some light on how can I call the method to generate subscription key from my c# application?

```
 SubscriptionResource subscription = await client.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
 ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
 ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync("rg_name");
 var apiManagements = await resourceGroup.GetApiManagementServiceAsync("apim_name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just have to keep going.

This worked for me ...

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

var resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
var resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync("rg-your-resource-group");
var apimInstance = await resourceGroup.Value.GetApiManagementServiceAsync("apim-your-instance");

var newSubscription = apimInstance.Value.GetApiManagementSubscriptions().CreateOrUpdate(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, "your_generated_sid",
    new Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement.Models.ApiManagementSubscriptionCreateOrUpdateContent()
    {
        DisplayName = "Display Name",
        State = Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement.Models.SubscriptionState.Active,
        Scope = "/products/Unlimited"
    });
```

... you'll just need to work out your `Scope`, `SID`, `DisplayName`, etc.

I suspect you'll want the primary key after it's created if you need to communicate back to the caller once setup.

That can be obtained in the response ...

```
var primaryKey = newSubscription.Value.Data.PrimaryKey;
```

Comment: Wow, thx.! I saw somewhere in the Azure documentation saying we can use our generated key (in GUID format) as the primary key by passing our key in the payload.

Comment: Maybe I've confused you or you've confused me but by `PrimaryKey` I mean the primary API key that the calling application will need to authenticate, that's usually done through the (standard) `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` parameter in the header of each call.  Either way, you're happy now.  :-)